# Using a library that is not thread-safe inside of a controller

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm not sure how threading works inside of play, from what I understand netty uses a single thread but not sure how this translates to how controller actions are called.

```
class SomeController extends Controller {

  val processor = new PegDownProcessor()  // 

  def index = Action { request => 

    val result = processor.doSomething()

    Ok("hello")
  }

}
```

The pegdown library says instantiating the PegDownProcessor could take 100's of milliseconds, and suggests to use a single reference in an application.

> Note that the first time you create a PegDownProcessor it can take up
>   to a few hundred milliseconds to prepare the underlying parboiled
>   parser instance. However, once the first processor has been built all
>   further instantiations will be fast. Also, you can reuse an existing
>   PegDownProcessor instance as often as you want, as long as you prevent
>   concurrent accesses, since neither the PegDownProcessor nor the
>   underlying parser is thread-safe.

https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown

It also says that it isn't thread-safe.

Is the above usage designed correctly where I use a single instance as a val inside of a controller, and actually use it inside of a controller action?

Please explain if it is correct i.e. thread-safe or why it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play actions can be called from multiple threads.

A quick solution that popped into my head:
You could create a pool of processors. The pool would be thread-safe and would contain a given number of processors (you could assign the number of processors dynamically or based on the CPU/RAM you have). When a request comes in, the pool puts it in a (FIFO) queue (of course you should use a thread-safe queue implementation). Each processor operates on its own thread, when one finishes a job, it checks the queue for a new job. The enqueue method of the pool returns a Future which is resolved when the task is processed. Play supports async results for the controller methods, so this would play nicely with Play as well.

A similar solution is to use Akka and its actor pool feature that basically implements the above approach in a more generic way. Since actors are single-threaded, each actor would have a single reference to a processor and would simply do the same as you would do on a single thread. Akka allows for advanced options, such as defining the scheduling method, and also fits nicely in the Play stack. Akka has almost no overhead itself, and you can create thousands of actors without any performance issues.

Comment: Makes sense, I like the Akka approach since it is a toolset built that can do exactly what I need really :)